# Run maven from bash script with parameters that has spaces

Tags: bash, maven

Have script

```
   while true; 
      do
        case "$1" in
         -l | --login ) LOGIN=$2; shift 2 ;;
         -- ) shift; break ;;
         * ) break ;;
        esac
     done  
   mvn clean install -Dlogin=\"$LOGIN\"
```

Run this script by: **run_mvn.sh --login "Admin Admin"**
Maven told:

```
andrew@andrew-desktop:~/App$ ./run.sh --login "Admin Admin" 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Reactor build order: 
[INFO]   Application
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Invalid task 'Admin"': you must specify a valid lifecycle phase, or a goal in the format plugin:goal or pluginGroupId:pluginArtifactId:pluginVersion:goal
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Sep 22 18:11:45 EEST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/119M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The build is successully when I ran **mvn clean install -Dlogin="Admin Admin"** only. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply quote the parameter expansion

```
mvn clean install -Dlogin="$LOGIN"
```

`mvn` will see one of its arguments as `-Dlogin=Admin Admin` (including the space), and will handle parsing the word itself.

The way you wrote the code, `mvn` was receiving two separate arguments, `-Dlogin="Admin` and `Admin"`. The escaped quotation marks did not prevent the expansion of `$LOGIN` from undergoing word-splitting, and themselves were passed as part of the expansion.